# How close and delete a modeless qt dialog

Tags: qt, memory-management, dialog, modeless

I have create a modeless qdialog inside a method of a class:

```
//Test.cpp

QDialogMaintenance *diag = new QDialogMaintenance(this);
diag->show();
diag->raise();
diag->activateWindow();
```

I can close the dialog only clicking on the "X" icon in the dialog frame. How can I delete the "diag" instance in the test.cpp?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [`QWidget::setAttribute`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setAttribute) and set the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute.

> Makes Qt delete this widget when the widget has accepted the close event (see QWidget::closeEvent()).

```
diag->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```